# VB.Net (2019) File I/O Mixed Data Help Please?

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I am old and used to older VBA in Excel and Older VB code.  Now I am trying to work in Visual Studio Community with VB.  I have looked for help but everything I find for .NET comes up with C++ or C# code which I don't follow.  I haven't even been able to find a book to help converting to the newer format of code.  I am used to;

```
Dim outpath as integer
Dim aString as String
Dim aDouble as Double
aString = "Some Text"
aDouble = 3.1429
outpath = FreeFile
Open "C:\afolder\somedata.dat" For Output As outpath
print #outpath, aString
print #outpath, aDouble
close #outpath
```

To read data I'm used to using the aString = input #outpath instructions.
From what I have read it appears I should be using IO.Stream functions but have not found anything that would replicate the old method I am used to above.

Can somebody please point me to some internet pages that cover this in VB rather than falling into C code which I cannot translate to VB.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-write-text-to-files-with-a-streamwriter

Comment: The official MS docs generally default to C# but there is normally an option to switch to vb.net specific syntax.  Normally towards the top right of the page

Comment: Thank you.   I can see how that works for "text strings" but not when a file is "txt string" as first record followed by aDouble as a stored value variable for example.  This method only seems to align with straight text  to switch to use another method to read or save an otherwise predefined record type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there are a number of ways to do this. I also came from VB6, and lots of VBA.

So, to convert your above, and to write out to a file?

Well, one apporach (and we even did this in VBA) was to create a string, concentante the values to the string, and then write the string out to a file.

It is easy, but you have to in code toss in the next line character.

So, this will work:

```
   Dim aString As String
    Dim aDouble As Double

    aString = "Some Text"
    aDouble = 3.1429

    Dim strPath As String = "C:\test\somedata.dat"

    Dim strOutBuf As String = ""
    strOutBuf = aString
    strOutBuf = strOutBuf & vbCrLf & aDouble

    File.WriteAllText(strPath, strOutBuf)
```

So, for a few easy lines of text - very easy.

However, for a lot of code, and a line by line output - similar to VBA?

Then you do it this way:

```
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\test\test2.txt"
    Dim MyFileWriter As New StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

    Dim aString As String
    Dim aDouble As Double

    aString = "Some Text"
    aDouble = 3.1429

    MyFileWriter.WriteLine(aString)
    MyFileWriter.WriteLine(aDouble)

    For i = 1 To 10
        MyFileWriter.WriteLine(i)
    Next

    MyFileWriter.Close()
```

Note that in above, the file does not (can not) already exist.

So, you have to deal with that issue.

You can either delete the file before you start writing.

eg:

```
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\test\test2.txt"

    If File.Exists(FILE_NAME) Then
        File.Delete(FILE_NAME)
    End If
```

(and then the rest of your code follows. So there no need (or concept) of FreeFile() anymore.

output:

```
Some Text
3.1429
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

***Edit: --------------------------------***

Well, showing how to write out a file is kind of like the hug, without the kiss. So, now, how can we read the file?

Well, it really depends on what we want to do with that input. But .net tends to work reading (or in fact writing) the whole thing in one shot.

But, a line by line read would look like this:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\test\test2.txt"


    Dim MyFileReader As New StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

    Do While MyFileReader.EndOfStream = False

        Debug.Print("one line of file = " & MyFileReader.ReadLine)

    Loop

    MyFileReader.Close()


End Sub

output:
one line of file = Some Text
one line of file = 3.1429
one line of file = 1
one line of file = 2
one line of file = 3
one line of file = 4
one line of file = 5
one line of file = 6
one line of file = 7
one line of file = 8
one line of file = 9
one line of file = 10
```

Comment: Thank you very much Albert.  I am going to go and play with that code and get a better feeling of how it works.   I am having horrible problems trying to use 'Immediate window' and breakpoints to delve into what is happening here.  Things used to be so much simpler.  Thank you again.

Comment: The ability to type a vb command in the immediate window is perhaps the most missed feature in vb.net. HOwever, the stepping of code, break points - it not much different the VBA, or VB6 - even the same keys work the same - so it not all bad.

Comment: Albert, I have to say I hit a number of problems.  In the first example of code the File.WriteAllText statement errored as the File was not 'declared' somehow I accidently clicked on a popup error code and it fixed but so quickly I didn't get what it actually did.                          The next code example with the StreamWriter worked great to output data BUT I tried to reverse it to become a StreamReader and kept hitting walls.   Sorry I can't see how to make this reply comment more readable here.

Comment: Hum, the first example should work - I did put in "air code" of a different file name - so you of course have to edit/change that code to a given folder and path name that you have on your computer. As for the reading? I posted a update that shows how we could/would read the file back in after writing it out - so see  the new edit part that has reading code.

Comment: You need an `Imports` directive for `System.IO`, or to fully qualify the type name: `System.File.IO.WriteAllText()`

Comment: Yes... the dreaded Imports System.IO.. it flashed past so fast I barely saw it !    Thank you for the kind update edit Albert.   I have tried to vote to support those who have supported me but I'm not sure if the system is doing that.  Forgive my lack of familiarity with the interface.  I'll get there.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
' vb.net has allowed declaration and assignment on the same line for more than 20yrs now
Dim aString as String = "Some Text"
Dim aDouble as Double = 3.1429

' New API methods do not use integers to track files. 
' That was always kind of weird. 
Dim outpath As String = "C:\afolder\somedata.dat"

' StreamReader/StreamWriter are great, and you should learn them, 
'  but you don't need them for this sample
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outpath, $"{aString}{vbCrLf}{aDouble}")
' Interpolated strings (like above) are kind of fun, too
```

Again, without the comments and assuming an `Imports` directive for `System.IO`, to highlight how simple this can be:

```vb
Dim aString as String = "Some Text"
Dim aDouble as Double = 3.1429
Dim outpath As String = "C:\afolder\somedata.dat"
File.WriteAllText(outpath, $"{aString}{vbCrLf}{aDouble}")
```

If the interpolated string is too confusing, here's one more option:

```vb
Dim aString as String = "Some Text"
Dim aDouble as Double = 3.1429
Dim outpath As String = "C:\afolder\somedata.dat"
File.WriteAllText(outpath, aString)
File.AppendAllText(outpath, aDouble.ToString("r"))
```

However, that actually opens, writes, and closes the file twice. It's extra I/O, which is some of the slowest stuff you can do in a computer, so I don't recommend it.

Instead, you could build the output string with concatenation, but I'm sure you're aware that can also be cumbersome, so here's a final alternative with a `System.IO.StreamWriter`:

```vb
Dim aString as String = "Some Text"
Dim aDouble as Double = 3.1429
Dim outpath As String = "C:\afolder\somedata.dat"

'Using blocks (added way back in 2005) replace the need to Close the file
' Moreover, they promise to dispose of the file handle
'  **even if there's an exception/error**,
'  making your code safer and better.
Using writer As New StreamWriter(outpath)
    writer.WriteLine(aString)
    writer.WriteLine(aDouble)
End Using
```

Then to read the values back:

```vb
Dim filePath As String = "C:\afolder\somedata.dat"

Dim aString as String
Dim aDouble as Double
Using reader As New StreamReader(filePath)
    aString = reader.ReadLine()
    aDouble = Double.Parse(reader.ReadLine())
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you Joel. :) I will take a step back and work through what you and Albert have shared.   Noted: on the 20yrs direct DIm with assignation of a variable content.  I guess this shows how I did Basic in a variety of flavours, but was really in my past life working in assembler on memory mapped IO machines.